# Correct and best practices for xpaths?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath

This is a just a quick question and answer, how can I shorten my xpath with the number of /div I have?  At what point do you say /div[X]?  Sorry a newbiw to Selenium and c# as an automated tester.

Here is my xpath below:\

```
//div[@class='vt-time-zone-select vt-form-field']/div/div/div/div/div/div/input
```

Comment: Hi guys I have just answered my won question.  Here is the short hand //div[@class='vt-time-zone-select vt-form-field']//input.  Hope it helps others

Comment: Your shortened expression might work for you, but it's not equivalent to the original. There are possible test documents where the two expressions will deliver different results. There is no way to shorten your original expression to one that is precisely equivalent.